# How to factor a third degree polynomial once you know one root?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $p(x) = 9x^3 - 30x^{2} + 29x - 8 $. If we wish to solve $p(x) = 0$, then we can observe that $x=1$ is a root of $p$. Then, we can write $(x-1)( \dots ) = 0$. How does one find the expression where the dots are in this particular example? And how does one do this in the general case?

Comment: The process is called [polynomial (long) division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). Do you have a textbook or the like that explains that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah I didn't know that, thank you. The explanation provided on the wikipedia page seems to be sufficient.

Comment: The fastest way to perform long division by $x-\alpha$  is *synthetic division* (a.k.a. *Horner's scheme*).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that long division is probably the simplest method of finding out the factors (*for a general case*)but I usually refrain from using it(*if the polynomial doesn't have higher degrees*) by adjusting the terms of the polynomials to get a second degree quadratic equation.This is how it is done-

Note that each parenthesis has a factor $(x-1)$ which is taken common from each parenthesis to get a simple expression
$$(9x^3-9x^2)+(-21x^2+21x)+(8x-8)=$$
$$9x^2(x-1)-21x(x-1)+8(x-1)=$$

Finally take $(x-1)$ common from the whole expression to get-
$$(x-1)(9x^2-21x+8)$$ 
Now one can easily factor out the quadratic if you want.

Comment: I have never seen this done, it's quite lovely; a definite +1 from me. Is it "rare" that this technique works (like, say, factoring a cubic by grouping) or can it be applied pretty generally, if one knows the linear factor? (I suspect it can be used in general, and will hopefully think about it)

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Divide}\;1-1\;\text{into}\;9-30+29-8$

$\begin{array}{rrrr}
9&-21&+8&\\
9&-30&+29&-8\\
9&-9&&\\
&-21&+29&\\
&-21&+21&\\
&&8&-8\\
&&8&-8
\end{array}$

$\text{So,}\;9x^2-21x+8=0\;\text{is your reduced equation.}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy-to-remember trick (It is the same basic idea as Freelancer's answer):

If some $x$ is known to be a solution to the equation $mx^3 + nx^2 +ox + p$, then we know that $(x-1)$ is one of the factors of the polynomial. As you say, the third order polynomial can then be written as $(x-1)(...)$. However, we know that the $(...)$ must be a second-order (quadratic) polynomial, since we factored an $x$ out when we pulled out that $(x-1)$. Thus, the $(...)$ is some quadratic with the form $(ax^2 + bx + c)$, such that

> $(x-1)(ax^2+bx+c) = mx^3 + nx^2 +ox + p$.

Now we just need to find the values for $a$, $b$, and $c$, find the solutions for that quadratic, and we'll be done.

Let's use your $p(x)=9x^3−30x^2+29x−8$ as an example.

#### We know $x = 1$ is one of the roots, so we say that $9x^3−30x^2+29x−8 = (x-1)(ax^2+bx+c)$.

Expanding out the right side gives $9x^3−30x^2+29x−8 = (x-1)(ax^2+bx+c) =ax^3+bx^2 + cx -ax^2 - bx - c = ax^3+(b-a)x^2+(c-b)x-c$

The rest is easy.

#### Finding c

1. Looking at the original $p(x)$, $c$ must be $8$, which gives $ax^3+(b-a)x^2+(8-b)x-8$

#### Finding b

2. $b$ is given with some algebra: Looking at $p(x)$, $8-b$ must equal $29$, and $8-b = 29$ gives $b = 8-29 \to b=-21$. That brings us to $ax^3+(-21-a)x^2+(8-(-21))x-8 = ax^3+(-21-a)x^2+(29)x-8$

#### Finding a

3. Just like with $c$, we can look at $p(x)$ to deduce that $a$ must be $9$, which gives $9x^3+(-21-9)x^2+21x-8 = 9x^3+(-30)x^2+21x-8 = 9x^3-30x^2+21x-8$.

#### Finding $(...)$

4. And so, we've found $a$, $b$, and $c$. Substitute these values into the quadratic form for $(x-1)(ax^2 + bx + c)$ and continue from there.